# Can DLL in .NET use a different extension, e.g. MLL?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio-2010, dll

I know this is a wacky question, but in Visual Studio 2010 C#.Net is there a way to name an Assembly with a different extension than DLL.  E.g., MyAssembly.MLL instead of MyAssembly.DLL.

I poked around but could not find a way to do it.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What do you stand to gain from it?

Comment: Could you expand on the intention behind that change?

Comment: You can just make a postbuild step that does `rename foo.dll foo.whackyshit`.  But I too am curious as to why you want to do that.

Comment: He may be using the extension to differentiate between his DLL and other DLLs, if he's loading it at runtime. I know Python does this for Python extension modules; they end in "pyd".

Comment: You probably *can*, and you'd be able to using it via `Assembly.CreateInstanceFromAndUnWrap` for example, as you pass a full path name of the file to load.  As to why you would do this is anyones guess, and you've said yourself it's a wacky question - so you've probably answered it yourself - "I can, but I really shouldn't".

Comment: @TaylorBrandstetter, there are existing methods for determining *which* Dll to use in the .NET environment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, I don't believe so - at least not without a bunch of extra work.

I've just tried this with a manual rename step, and although you can *compile* against a renamed assembly, it won't be found at execution time. The code will contain a reference to `MyAssembly`, and the runtime will try to resolve that to `MyAssembly.dll` and `MyAssembly.exe`... but it won't know the *actual* filename you used. It's *possible* that there's a way of configuring this within `app.config` or using [`AppDomain.AssemblyResolve`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) to resolve the assembly yourself - but I strongly suspect other things may break.

Aside from anything else, I would discourage you from doing this just in terms of unconventionality. You'll surprise other developers, tools etc - not a good idea.

Comment: Correct. Same thing for short file names.  Windows Installer has a datatype that is used by the Directory and File tables to support short names on legacy systems.  .NET doesn't like this at all.

Comment: +1.  But am I right in thinking that he *could* load it via `Assembly.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap`, for example (and I am by no means insinuating he *should*!)

Comment: @Moo-Juice: Or AppDomain.AssemblyResolve, as I've just written in the edited answer. It's possible that either of those would work, but I'm not going to put in much effort to find out.

Comment: @JonSkeet, don't blame you at all :)

Comment: @JonSkeet - thanks. That is what I anticipated. Thanks for actually trying it out.

Comment: I have done this and it does load using Assembly.CreateInstance. I was curious about this as well and went looking for an approach to loading an assembly at run-time that could be used to connect my application to a back-end database. The approach worked but I abandoned it for the very reasons Jon mentions above.